# Is a lifting of a smooth curve also smooth?

Tags: calculus, smooth-functions

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous map such that the map $[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2,t\mapsto e^{2\pi if(t)}$ is smooth ($C^\infty$). Then is $f$ also smooth?

I tried to use the fact that $\arccos$ and $\arcsin$ are smooth if the domain is restricted to the interior. But I don't know what to do at the endpoints.

Comment: There is no connection between $f$ and $t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$.

Comment: Do you mean that $t \mapsto e^{2\pi i f(t)}$ is smooth?

Comment: Consider the fact that $\Bbb R\ni t\longmapsto e^{2\pi it}\in \Bbb S^1$ is a local diffeomorphism. Now, a diffeomorphism composition smooth map is smooth. That's all you need. @zxcv

Comment: @Aryaman Oops, I will correct my question.

Comment: @Sumanta Thanks. But I meant that it is smooth as a function into $\mathbb R^2$ (not $S^1$). I will edit my question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Note that both $\cos (2\pi f(t))$ and $\sin (2\pi f(t))$ are smooth. Near an arbitrary real number, at least one of $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ does not cause an endpoint related problem. So we can use the one not causing the problem. That is, if $f(t_0)=0$, then we cannot use $\arccos$, but since $\arcsin$ is smooth near $0$, we see that $2\pi f(t)(=\arcsin \sin 2\pi f(t))$ is smooth near $t_0$.